# Generate custom invervals per id and fill-down with existing - Python

Tags: python

I have the following data:

[image]

I need:

[image]

I cannot figure out the function I should use. Can you, please, direct me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
for n in df['interval']:
    newdf = newdf.append(pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df[df['interval']==n].values,n,axis=0)))
newdf.columns = df.columns
```

Comment: Thank you, again, I got the desired outcome!